Would a flipped Northern Hemisphere still have huge deserts in the Sahara and Siberia?

I am making alternate history timelines where Earth has radically different geographies. I noticed one day that a huge chunk of Earth's land area is near the Arctic Circle. Canada, Siberia, Alaska, Greenland, and Svalbard are in the Arctic region. In my alternate timeline, those lands are moved to warmer regions while central Africa, parts of South America, and Indonesia are flipped to the Arctic. Earth just naturally forms like this during the Cenozoic Era.
Given this scenario, would there still be large deserts in Africa, Siberia, and Arabia? I partially did this to try and increase Earth's farmland. Although the melting of Greenland could raise sea levels and cause issues.

You're not going to be able to get a definitive answer because desertification occurs over time.  Civilisation arose in the Fertile Crescent, but if you look at those areas today they are largely less-fertile and/or outright desert.  Additionally, "what effect would X have on climate" are some of the hardest questions to answer given the number of intertwined factors involved.

Remember that the Earth is not a rectangle.

The deserts and the tundra/polar areas are hot/cold due to the effects of Hadley Cell circualtion, that will not change in the described scenario. The climatic latitude bands are going to remain unchanged so what is now southern Greenland (on the new map) will be tropical, Siberia and the Eurasian Steppe become subtropical deserts and what was the Caribbean is now frozen Arctic Ocean. My initial marque 1 eyeball estimate says you've actually drastically reduced the availability of arable land, especially by desertifying the steppes, much of that land can be highly productive where water is available.
